To draw a tetrahedron with its center
I need a tetrahedron with a its center and I would like to label all of them, but I do not know how to find a way for the center. I saw this To draw a labeled tetrahedron. For my case I need a tetrahedron having segments from its center to other vertices. Is it possible? Your help is highly appreciated.

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    z={(-.3cm,-.4cm)},
    line join=round, 
    line cap=round,  
    every node/.style={
        inner sep=1pt, 
        font=\scriptsize
    }
]
 \fill[] (-2,0,0) -- (2,0,0) -- (0,0,-2);
    \draw
        (0,2,0) node[above] {C} --
        (-2,0,0) node[left] {T} --
       % (0,0,0) node[below] {C1} --
        (2,0,0) node[right] {M} -- cycle
        (0,0,0) -- (0,0,0);
    \draw[dashed] 
        (0,2,0) -- (0,0,-2) node[below] {S} 
        (2,0,0) -- (0,0,-2) -- (-2,0,0);
        
\end{tikzpicture}

I need a tetrahedron with a center ( like the pink point inside) without x and y axes, but with edges from the point on the center to other nodes too. with labels for each nodes.
) .
I need the following tetrahedron such that the point inside along with edges from that are pink)


First you look up some of the maths to help you with the trigonometry.  Then you might get more help here if you make an attempt and ask a specific question here if you get stuck.

You can use 3dtools
   \documentclass[border=3.14 mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=7
        0,psi=0,theta=70},line cap=butt,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},declare function={a=4;}]
\path
   (a,0,0) coordinate (C)
(-a/2,{a*sqrt(3)/2},0) coordinate (D)
(-a/2,{-a*sqrt(3)/2},0) coordinate (B)
(0,0,{a*sqrt(6)/4}) coordinate (A);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybarycenter}{barycenter("(A),(B),(C),(D)")}
\path (\mybarycenter) coordinate (E);
        \draw[red, ultra thick]   (E) -- (A) (E) -- (B) (E) -- (C) (E) -- (D);
    \draw[ ultra thick] (D) -- (C) -- (A) -- (B) --cycle (D) --(A) (C) -- (B);
             \fill[3d/screen coords,ball color=pink] (E) circle (0.15);
    \path foreach \p/\g in {A/90,B/180,C/-90,D/90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\node[ label={-100:$E$}] at (E) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for your help. Actually, in my edited question I uploaded a photo for the one which I need, Can you please help me to draw that.

@user118746 Centroid of the tetrahedron must be the point (0,0,0)?

It can be any point.

I really appreciate your time. I want to connect C to B via a segment not a dot-line, and also connect the centroid of the tetrahedron to A,B, C, and D via dot-lines,  And remove the x,y,z-axes.

It is very simple. To draw segmen IA noot dot -- line, you use \draw (I) -- (A); If you draw dot - line, you can use \draw[dashed] (I) -- (A);

Thank you very much

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-platon}
\begin{document}

\psTetrahedron
\psTetrahedron[Frame=false,Viewpoint=-1 0.5 2] 
\psTetrahedron[Frame=false,Viewpoint=0.7 -0.5 -0.8]

\end{document}


See also package pst-solides3d
